# Clone or fresh install for HDD to SSD change?

Tags: 20.04, hard-drive, ssd

I have read (most of) the recent (18 and later releases) comments on my question.  Current system 20.04.2 LTS, 2 Tbyte HDD.  Plan to replace with a Crucial 2 TB SSD.  In the past, when I have moved from one drive to another, including to a larger capacity drive (e.g., from a 1 Tbyte HDD to a 2 Tbyte HDD), I use an external cloning device in which the source and target drives are inserted and a clone is made.  If the new drive is larger than the source drive, after installing the new drive into the computer (the same one from which the lower capacity drive was removed) and booting, I then use gparted to either increase the size of existing partitions or add additional partitions and mount points (e.g., if /opt were within the / partition on the original drive, I will make one of the new partitions /opt1, mv everything from /opt to /opt1, `rm -rf /opt`, and then `mv /opt1 /opt` , all as root , etc.).  In the present case, the HDD and the SSD have the same nominal capacity (2 Tbyte) with the reason for the SSD is lower access times (higher data throughput).  With this preamble, is this method going to work or is it better to do a clean install of 20.04 and then, using an external drive enclosure to USB 3, as root `cp -pra` from /opt, say, on the old drive to /opt on the new booted SSD that has the fresh install?  A related question:  are the HDD kernel drivers and the SSD kernel drivers -- on the same interface, say SATA -- the same driver, or does the kernel recognise the specific type of internal drive to use the higher data throughput of a SSD over a HDD?

Comment: I have always believed in new install. That also gives the choice to reorganize and housecleans lots of old logs & other cruft. I find my install partitions change when I get a new drive usually about every 3 years or so. And now UEFI with gpt partitioning is more common, but users may have have correctly installed. Most desktops do not need more than / (root) and ESP if UEFI. And should use gpt. Separate /home and use of swap partition then are optional.

Comment: Is there a way to keep identical partitions (size and type) when the old and new drive have the same nominal capacity (2 Tbyte in this case)?  E.g., output a file from the existing drive that can be input into the LTS installer (from DVD when "booted" for install) to perform the identical partitions?  Once that is done, one creates tar.gz of each of the old partitions and then feeds these into the "new" system once the disk has been created.  Likewise, is there a mechanism to output all of the existing .deb packages and have these then downloaded and installed by the new system?

Comment: If keeping both drives, you cannot totally clone as dupllicate UUIDs are not allowed. You can copy /home & your data partitions, especially if separate partitions to new drive similar to this: To move /home uses rsync- Be sure to use parameters to preserve ownership & permissions 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving  Best to just do new install & restore from backup. Then you also know you backup procedure includes everything including list of installed apps for when hard drive fails (not if). And you still have old drive to go back to, if backup is not complete.

Comment: Both drives would not be installed -- target machine is a laptop with one drive "bay".  However, if the other (original HDD) is placed in a USB adapter and thus presented to the computer as a USB, not internal, harddrive device, my understanding is that the USB "harddrive" OS interface generates a new UUID.  As for preserving ownership, etc., a tar does that.  If the original owner does not appear, then as root one does a ```chown``` and ```chgrp``` both ```-R``` to assign to a user on the "new" system.

Comment: No matter how drive is connected SATA or USB3 the UUID will be the same. So do not rely on that. You can edit one install or the other to have new UUIDs & if you still want to boot it edit fstab & every other place UUID is used. Tar is old school (tape backup) and really only for smaller amounts of data. But required if copying to a Windows format partition as backup. If just your data you can use chown & chmod, but not for system files as they vary.

Comment: To be clear -- both drives will not be internally mounted to the machine at the same time.  Is there a way to run, say, ```dd``` to clean-up internal and external fragmentation at the same time it is making a partition copy?  Is there a way to create a file from the present partitioning and file system types that I use as an input into the installer on a new drive so that partitions are identical?  By that mechanism, if dd will do defragementation during a copy, once I install a minimal new system with the SAME partitions as my present one, I could then simply defrag dd to keep what I want.

Comment: dd is a bit for bit copy including any empty space. Drives must be identical down to sectors, sometimes same size drives do not have same number of sectors. Defrag is a Windows thing, Linux does not do defrag as it organized data on drive totally differently. It is not hard to use gparted to create partitions. Is system UEFI or BIOS or really then MBR as Windows has to have MBR for BIOS boot or UEFI which should be gpt partitioned.

Comment: Let me try this differently.  If not tar.gz, then what (as universal)?  How do I save my present partitions and partition file system types (I do not use secure boot) without printing out the details and manually (re)entering these during partitioning of the "fresh" install?  How do I "cp -pra" (or whatever) to restore contents (but not "fragmentation") from the existing HDD to the new SSD once the new SSD boots?  I want a defragmented (internal and external fragmentation is common to almost all filesytems, including those on Linux) image on the new SSD.  Also, parameters to increase SSD life.

Comment: Some are backup & some are image. I prefer rsync for backup/copy. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem & http://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools I see suggestions for this: http://clonezilla.org/ which is an image copy. Best practice for Backups - theFu
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2436006